# How to obtain the true name of a file from a MSI (or, how to read the MSI database) in Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, cab

**UPDATE:** I changed this question's title to reflect what is really needed from some of the answers below.

I want to be able, within Linux, to obtain a particular executable file from a MSI generated from within Visual Studio 2010's native deployment tool. But the names obtained by cabextract are all funky:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel     159 Jul 16 17:26 _07DAC52BD05CC8A8D6B2195350CC8C13
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel   34304 Oct 29 12:10 _09C75789ECE59A0AC891A85289474E75
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel    8704 Oct 29 12:10 _0CB147FD23752DEFAC3B73925E1E38DB
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel     766 Oct 29 12:10 _1D0B16C3296C400D9FD4018E77AC0B05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel   10752 Oct 29 12:10 _24792622E94742D68A455C4F1D54D51F
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel     159 Oct 29 12:10 _90A663D25084CD22A230CCB8F55A3700
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel   12800 Oct 29 12:10 _BC47FBF48B42E5E71C9901188422814A
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel  873984 Oct 29 12:10 _EAFFD36EAA914E7F9D3DAC8BA13DFB6A
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel    4608 Oct 29 12:10 _F434E52DDE0AB5C2D68CE7A78B0B2477
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel  467456 Oct 29 12:10 _F90AF0EB7EEF445A92623132D00191EA
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel  421200 Oct 29 12:10 F_CENTRAL_msvcp100_x86.AFA96EB4_FA9F_335C_A7CB_36079407553D
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel  773968 Oct 29 12:10 F_CENTRAL_msvcr100_x86.AFA96EB4_FA9F_335C_A7CB_36079407553D
```

Comparing with the solution's Release directory, I can see that the file I want (itragent.exe) is actually _F90AF0EB7EEF445A92623132D00191EA -- is there a way to come to that conclusion programatically, within Linux? Either using cabextract or with the help of some other utility? There's two files in there that are XML text, but all they have is .NET Framework version information and nothing else.

Alternative, is there a way to force VS 2010 to file the executables within the MSI with their correct names?

Answer (score 1):

There is problem, cab doesn't contain information regarding the "true" names of files. But it contain the order of these files. MSI file has table `File`, where every compressed file has `Sequence` number. This number should be identical to the sequence number of the file within the cabinet.

I think, you could open the MSI, take real file names from column `FileName` and their `Sequence` number, and somehow equate them to cab sequence.

The useful links: [Description of CAB Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx), [information regarding File table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Windows Installer SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The cab files are named after a primary key in the .msi database. To find their real names, you have to look in the database. The tables you need include [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596.aspx) if you just need the `FileName` (lookup from `File`), or for relative paths, you also need [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368295.aspx) (a self-linked tree of directory locations; see Rob Menshing's series on the [Directory table](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2005/06/21/431294.aspx) if you need help making sense of it) and [Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007.aspx) as the many-to-many lookup table into it.

Mind you that in some pathological cases, multiple entries in the cab may have the same pathnames once you're done, so you may have to handle these specially. This should be relatively rare.

Comment: Ah, I see. Now all I need is some way to read this database from within Linux. Is there some already-made utility that does that?

Comment: It looks like Wine supports the Windows Installer APIs. You might start looking up APIs: MsiOpenDatabase, MsiDatabaseOpenView, MsiViewExecute, MsiViewFetch, MsiRecordGetString.